# how to receive email using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am using node.js and nodemailer and I am able to send email to a dedicated gmail account.

However, I want to connect to the gmail account as a client and receive all emails that are sent to that gmail account.

All of the examples here on stack overflow regarding nodemailer are about sending email. I cannot find any thing about receiving email.

How do I do this?

Thanks,

Andres

Comment: What code have you tried so far? We will not just give you code, you need to show some effort.

Answer (score 4):

well actually nodemailer seems to be a "send e-mails" library only (cf http://www.nodemailer.com/)
you may take a look at http://mailin.io/ (not tested personally ..)

Comment: mailin.io ... nice documentation set too!

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer is a module to send email messages.

I finded this [article](https://medium.com/@akinremiolumide96/reading-email-data-with-node-js-cdacaa174cc7)